# Cross-compiling to ARM

Tags: arm, llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to cross-compile from x86 to ARM using LLVM. I have built a standard version of LLVM on x86 (which works). Now I am running the following command:

```
clang++ -v -g3 -O0 $< -o $@ $(FLAGS) -rdynamic --target=${ARM_TRIP} \
    --sysroot=${SYSROOT}/libc \
    -I${SYSROOT}/include/c++/8.2.1 \
    -I${SYSROOT}/include/c++/8.2.1/${ARM_TRIP} \
    -L${SYSROOT}/lib/gcc/${ARM_TRIP}/8.2.1 \
    -B${SYSROOT}/bin
```

`ARM_TRIP` is my platform triple, `arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

It compiles fine, but can't link (I am using the arm linker), because LLVM is passing X86 arguments to the linker:

```
"/path/to/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld" \
--sysroot=/path/to/libc -export-dynamic -EL -X --hash-style=gnu \
--no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr -m armelf_linux_eabi -export-dynamic \
-dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -o kld-arm (more files...) \
-lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMGlobalISel (etc...)
```

The problem I'm seeing is the `-lLLVMX86*`. How do I change this to ARM? The files exist on my system, but LLVM seems to not be recognize that it needs to change this for my ARM target. Do I need to do something special when compiling LLVM, to tell that I may want to cross-compile? Or am I just not calling it correctly?

Comment: I was never able to get this fully working, but if using `llvm-config`, one thing I realized was that `llvm-config --libs native` will give the x86 libs, but if the AArch64 libs are installed, `llvm-config --libs aarch64` will link those libs instead.